# compare two excel sheet and print the difference?

Tags: linux, shell, perl, text-processing

I have two excel sheet (sheetA and sheetB) and I need to compare one column from sheetA with sheetB and print the difference.

**sheetA**

```
Account Number  |    Status
----------------|-------------
876251251       |    Not Active
716126181       |    Not Active
888281211       |    Not Active
666615211       |    Not Active
787878787       |    Not Active
111212134       |    Not Active
```

**sheetB**

```
Customer Number 
----------------
876251251
716126181
792342108
792332668
666615211
760332429
791952441
676702288
```

I need to compare "Account Number" with "Customer Number".

- All account numbers from `sheetA` should be present in customer number in `sheetB` and if sheetB is missing any "account number" then we should print out those info.
- And all those extra customer numbers in `sheetB` that are not present in `sheetA` account number, I want to print that as well.

I was reading about `awk` and I think we can it using `awk` but not able to understand how to do it?

```
$ awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{c[$1$2]++;next};c[$1$2] > 0' sheetB sheetA
```

Output should be:

```
Account Number:
888281211
787878787
111212134

CustomerNumber:
792342108
792332668
760332429
791952441
676702288
```

Comment: What is your expected result? Can you post ?

Comment: Not enough for an answer, but my 2 cents: 1. The modern Excel file format, suffix .xlsx, is xml based and hence can probably be parsed with tools like [xml_grep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xml_grep). For more sophisticated results you'll probably want to use Perl or another scripting language with XML plugins. 2. If you can get a CSV output you are probably able to parse it with the traditional *nix tools awk, sed and bash proper.

Comment: @Kalanidhi updated my question with the output

Comment: **"compare two excel sheet"** - you cannot use text processing against the excel `.xls` files (you must dump them to text or .csv first) the Excel file format contains MUCH MUCH more than what you see on the screen. (try opening the excel files in Notepad and see what all is there -- ouch!)

Comment: tagging of this question is off. It has nothing to do with all given tag categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VlookUp will work for this kind of matching.

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,B2:B9,1,FALSE)
```

[image]

Matching numbers from column "AccountNumber" with "customer number" and resulting the matched numbers of column 1. Filter out N/A (Not matched) you will get all numbers which are not matched from column 1.

For Different sheets

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7,1,FALSE)
```

Considering sheet 1 is ACnumbers and sheet2 has Custnumber

Comment: In my case I have two different excel sheets(not in one sheet).. Will your suggestion works on two different excel sheet?

Comment: Yes it will work, while selecting B2, select it from other sheet.

Comment: =VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7,1,FALSE)
Considering sheet 1 is ACnumbers and sheet2 has Custnumber

Comment: Both of my sheets (sheet1 and sheet2) have lot of columns but "AccountNumber" is the first column in sheet1 and "Customer Number" is the first column in sheet2 always. So considering I have seet1 and sheet2 as you described, where I am supposed to run the above formula `=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7,1,FALSE)`. I am relatively new to vlookup so trying to understand that..

Comment: @falsh I had taken the same, I'm trying to populate results in sheet2 just beside customer number column, so select A2 which is "CustomerNumber" 1st value,and then select Shee11 "AccountNumber" column all items form A2 to A7, and 1 is for index of your column, False for exact match. Hope you got it. It works as you expected.